# Python permission denied using Ubuntu in Windows 10

Tags: permissions, python, windows-10

I recently installed Ubuntu on my Windows 10 PC, and I tried running Python but I got:

```
-bash: /mnt/c/cygwin/bin/python: Permission denied
```

I've tried running `sudo apt install` and `sudo apt upgrade` and have also tried running the command as the administrator but these options also didn't work.

Would anybody know what the problem might be and what I can try? Thanks.

Comment: Is your user member of sudoer group? If you are not sure you can run ```sudo  -v <some random command>``` .```-v``` will give you an error if you are not, in form of```Sorry, user [username] may not run sudo on [hostname]```.

Comment: I just ran that command, and I got some `sudo` usage help messages, which I'm assuming means my member is a part of the sudoer group.

Comment: I managed to solve the issue by deleting Cygwin completely, but I'm not sure if that would exactly "solve" it. Perhaps someone more knowledgeable would be able to answer.

Comment: What *version* of Ubuntu did you install via WSL, and how did you install `python`? Ubuntu 20.04 ships with only `python3` by default, so it wouldn't find `python` in the usual Ubuntu search path (unless you installed the `python-is-python3` package) - presumably it then made its way down the WSL-added Windows `PATH` until it happened to find a `python` executable in Cygwin.